# Inconsistent "UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment" error, with the variable defined inside the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I've been making a simple Text RPG using **Python** and I've been getting an error occasionally, but not every time.

Sometimes when I go through the sequence, to get to the fight, it will give me the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment
```

or

```
enemy name not defined
```

The error always originates from **line 101**, inside the fightScreen() function:

```
enemy["level"] = player["level"]
```

I've already Googled and searched on Stack Overflow and found it's a problem with functions trying to redefine a variable instead of using one from before, but in my case the variable (dictionary) is defined inside the function itself.

I don't understand what's causing it and especially why it only happens **sometimes**

Minimal example (I think this chunk might be related to the problem):

```
player = {
  "name" : "player",
  "level" : 1,
  "ATK" : 5,
  "DEF" : 5,
  "CurHP" : 10,
  "MaxHP" : 10,
  "CurINV" : 0,
  "MaxINV" : 20
}

def randomEnemy():
  monsters = ['Goblin','Slime']
  random_enemy = random.choice(monsters)
  return random_enemy

def fightScreen():
  if randomEnemy() == "Goblin":
    enemy = { #GOBLIN
      "name" : "Goblin",
      "level" : 1,
      "ATK" : 2,
      "DEF" : 2,
      "CurHP" : 5,
      "MaxHP" : 5
    }
  elif randomEnemy() == "Slime":  
    enemy = { #SLIME
      "name" : "Slime",
      "level" : 1,
      "ATK" : 1,
      "DEF" : 3,
      "CurHP" : 5,
      "MaxHP" : 5
    }
  enemy["level"] = player["level"]
  enemy["ATK"] = (enemy["level"] * enemy["ATK"])
  enemy["DEF"] = (enemy["level"] * enemy["DEF"])
  enemy["MaxHP"] = (enemy["level"] * enemy["MaxHP"])
  enemy["CurHP"] = enemy["MaxHP"]
  playerStatus()
```

Here's the full code

```
import re
import random
import os

#player values
player = {
  "name" : "player",
  "level" : 1,
  "ATK" : 5,
  "DEF" : 5,
  "CurHP" : 10,
  "MaxHP" : 10,
  "CurINV" : 0,
  "MaxINV" : 20
}

#predefined variables
loop_i = 1
answer_yes = {'yes', 'y'}
answer_no = {'no', 'n'}
go_world = {'world', 'w'}
go_home = {'home', 'h'}
go_church = {'church', 'c'}
go_blacksmith = {'blacksmith', 'b'}
go_return = {'return', 'run', 'r'}
go_fight = {'fight', 'f'}

#defined functions for input
#ask a question and filter answer from non-letters and spaces
def questionAsked(question):
  inputRaw = input(question + ':')
  inputFiltered = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', inputRaw)
  return inputFiltered

def cls():
  #os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
  print('\n' * 30)

def playerStatus():
  print ("ATK ",player["ATK"]," | DEF ",player["DEF"]," | HP ",player["CurHP"],"/",player["MaxHP"]," | INV ",player["CurINV"],"/",player["MaxINV"]," | LV",player["level"],sep='')

def randomEnemy():
  monsters = ['Goblin','Slime']
  random_enemy = random.choice(monsters)
  return random_enemy

# screens-------------------------
#enemy prints
def printGoblin():
  print ("--------------------[FIGHT]-------------------")
  print ("|                .                            |")
  print ("|               |                  | .        |")
  print ("|              |                  |//         |")
  print ("|             |  \       /       /  /         |")
  print ("|             |___\     /____  /   /          |")
  print ("|            | \°_\     /°__/ /   /           |")
  print ("|            '               |  /             |")
  print ("|             |   (° °)       -               |")
  print ("|              | _________    |               |")
  print ("|               ||ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ|   .|               |")
  print ("|               | -------   |                 |")
  print ("|                |_________|                  |")
  print ("|_____________________________________________|")

def printSlime():
  print ("--------------------[FIGHT]-------------------")
  print ("|                       ______                |")
  print ("|                ______/      \_              |")
  print ("|              _/               \             |")
  print ("|             /    \     /       \_           |")
  print ("|            /    0       0        \          |")
  print ("|           /                       \         |")
  print ("|           /        ____            |        |")
  print ("|          /                         |        |")
  print ("|          /                          \       |")
  print ("|         /____________________________\      |")
  print ("|                                             |")
  print ("|                                             |")
  print ("|_____________________________________________|")

# fighting -----------------------
def fightScreen():
  if randomEnemy() == "Goblin":
    enemy = { #GOBLIN
      "name" : "Goblin",
      "level" : 1,
      "ATK" : 2,
      "DEF" : 2,
      "CurHP" : 5,
      "MaxHP" : 5
    }
  elif randomEnemy() == "Slime":  
    enemy = { #SLIME
      "name" : "Slime",
      "level" : 1,
      "ATK" : 1,
      "DEF" : 3,
      "CurHP" : 5,
      "MaxHP" : 5
    }
  enemy["level"] = player["level"]
  enemy["ATK"] = (enemy["level"] * enemy["ATK"])
  enemy["DEF"] = (enemy["level"] * enemy["DEF"])
  enemy["MaxHP"] = (enemy["level"] * enemy["MaxHP"])
  enemy["CurHP"] = enemy["MaxHP"]
  playerStatus()
  if enemy['name'] == "Goblin": #If enemy is GOBLIN
    printGoblin()
    print ("[",enemy["name"], ", LV", enemy["level"]," | HP ",enemy["CurHP"], "/",enemy["MaxHP"],"] ", "Fight (f) | Run (r)", sep='')
    print ("-----------------------------------------------")
    while enemy["CurHP"] > 0:
      userInput = questionAsked("What will you do?").lower()
      if userInput in go_fight:
        cls()
        printGoblin()
        print("You dealt ", (player["ATK"] - enemy["DEF"]) ," damage", sep='')
        enemy["CurHP"] = enemy["CurHP"] - (player["ATK"] - enemy["DEF"])
        if enemy["CurHP"] <= 0:
          print ("You won!")
          input("Press ENTER to go back")
          cls()
          Main()
        else:
          input("Press ENTER to continue")
          cls()
          printGoblin()
          print ("[",enemy["name"], ", LV", enemy["level"]," | HP ",enemy["CurHP"], "/",enemy["MaxHP"],"] ", "Fight (f) | Run (r)", sep='')
          print ("-----------------------------------------------")
      elif userInput in go_return:
        cls()
        Main()
        break

  elif enemy['name'] == "Slime": #If enemy is SLIME
    printSlime()
    print ("[",enemy["name"], ", LV", enemy["level"]," | HP ",enemy["CurHP"], "/",enemy["MaxHP"],"] ", "Fight (f) | Run (r)", sep='')
    print ("-----------------------------------------------")
    while enemy["CurHP"] > 0:
      userInput = questionAsked("What will you do?").lower()
      if userInput in go_fight:
        cls()
        printSlime()
        print("You dealt ", (player["ATK"] - enemy["DEF"]) ," damage", sep='')
        enemy["CurHP"] = enemy["CurHP"] - (player["ATK"] - enemy["DEF"])
        if enemy["CurHP"] <= 0:
          print ("You won!")
          input("Press ENTER to go back")
          cls()
          Main()
        else:
          input("Press ENTER to continue")
          cls()
          printSlime()
          print ("[",enemy["name"], ", LV", enemy["level"]," | HP ",enemy["CurHP"], "/",enemy["MaxHP"],"] ", "Fight (f) | Run (r)", sep='')
          print ("-----------------------------------------------")
      elif userInput in go_return:
        cls()
        Main()
        break

def forestScreen():
  playerStatus()
  print ("--------------------[Forest]-------------------")
  print ("|  *      *      **  |  |  * **   **    **    |")
  print ("| * *      *    **   |  |**    **   *    **   |")
  print ("|  *     ***   *    |  |*        *   *     ** |")
  print ("|   *    __________________________  *     ** |")
  print ("|    |  §                          §      *   |")
  print ("|    |_ §   You've encountered a   §      *   |")
  print ("|       §         Monster!         §      **  |")
  print ("|       § Fight(f)        Run(r)   §        * |")
  print ("|       §__________________________§          |")
  print ("| **       *   *    |  |    **                |")
  print ("|   **      | |    |  |   **  ***  ***      **|")
  print ("|     *     |_|   |  |   *      **    *    *  |")
  print ("|_____________________________________________|")
  print ("Fight (f) | Run (r)")
  print ("-----------------------------------------------")
  userInput = questionAsked("What will you do?").lower()
  if userInput in go_fight:
    cls()
    fightScreen()
  elif userInput in go_return: 
    print ('coward')
    cls()
    Main()

def townScreen():
  playerStatus()
  print ("--------------------[Town]---------------------")
  print ("|       +                       **       |*   |")
  print ("|      / \ Church         Home           |    |")
  print ("|     /   \          /////////\           | **|")
  print ("|    /     \    * *  |_____||_|           | * |")
  print ("| l==|°   °|         *             World _|___|")
  print ("| |__|_||__|          *               => _____|")
  print ("|                                         |   |")
  print ("|                           ##             |  |")
  print ("|           Blacksmith    ###               | |")
  print ("|   * *    //////////\  __#                 | |")
  print ("|   *      |         |__||        *         | |")
  print ("|          |_||______|___|         **      | *|")
  print ("|__________________________________________|__|")
  print ("  Info: Player(p) | Stats (s) | Inventory (i)")
  print ("-----------------------------------------------")
  userInput = questionAsked("Where do you want to go?").lower()
  return userInput

# Main executor, menu ------------------
def Main():
  while loop_i > 0:
    if townScreen() in go_world:
      print('Going to world...')
      cls()
      forestScreen()
      break
    elif townScreen() in go_home:
      print('Going home...')
    elif townScreen() in go_church:
      print('Going to church...')
    elif townScreen() in go_blacksmith:
      print('Going to blacksmith...')  
    else:
      print('What?')

# Sequence start-----------------------------------------------------  
while loop_i > 0:
  userInput = questionAsked("Start (Y/N)?").lower()
  if userInput in answer_yes:
    print ("Okay, let's do it")
    break;
  elif userInput in answer_no:
    print ("That's too bad")
    break;
  else:
    print ('What?')
  print("So your answer is " + userInput + ".")
cls()
Main()
```

Comment: I will quote the close reason: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.***
It is not ok to provide the code *solely* in an outside site. You **must** include the code necessary to understand the question in the question body itself. Extra links are fine, but the question should not depend on external links since they can break in the future and SO aims to have valuable content that lasts forever.

Comment: I did say where the error occurs, the desired behaviour is to not get the reference error and the reason why I posted an external link to the entire code is because I myself am unsure where I made a mistake, as I stated in the question.

Comment: @Roko No, you need to provide a [mcve]. Links to code are not appropriate replacements for a [mcve]

Comment: I checked the [licensing terms of repl.it](https://repl.it/site/docs/misc/licensing) and they say your content is MIT hence I've included it in the question as required. This is how you should have done from the start. Now if the link breaks the question can still stand.

Comment: Okay, I just thought it's way too many lines of code to post here, didn't want to clutter

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta  just dumping all your code and asking for debugging help is not on-topic. They should be providing a [mcve]

Comment: @Roko it is. Hence the *minimal* of minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've edited it so it includes a chunk of code I think might be relevant to the problem

Comment: So how do I reproduce this error? You haven't even provided the full error messages. Have you actually read the link I've posted multiple times about what a [mcve] is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just have to look at the following lines:

```
def fightScreen():
  if randomEnemy() == "Goblin":
    enemy = …
  elif randomEnemy() == "Slime":  
    enemy = …
  enemy["level"] = player["level"]
```

Simple question: What happens if `randomEnemy()` returns something other than "Goblin" or "Slime"? In this case, `enemy` is not defined.

Or, as that cannot happen, in the first call returns `"Slime"`, but on the second call it returns `"Goblin"`? Then you have `enemy` undefined and your error occurs.

Simple solution:

```
def fightScreen():
  enemyName = randomEnemy()
  if enemyName == "Goblin":
    enemy = …
  elif enemyName == "Slime":  
    enemy = …
```

Or, as long as these are really the only alternatives:

```
def fightScreen():
  if randomEnemy() == "Goblin":
    enemy = …
  else:
    enemy = …
```

---

But I would make a completely different concept: let your enemy types be classes.

Then you have something like

```
…
class Goblin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Goblin"
        self.level = 1
        self.ATK = 2
        self.DEF = 2
        self.curHP = 5
        self.maxHP = 5

    def print(self):
      print ("--------------------[FIGHT]-------------------")
      print ("|                .                            |")
      print ("|               |                  | .        |")
      print ("|              |                  |//         |")
      print ("|             |  \       /       /  /         |")
      print ("|             |___\     /____  /   /          |")
      print ("|            | \°_\     /°__/ /   /           |")
      print ("|            '               |  /             |")
      print ("|             |   (° °)       -               |")
      print ("|              | _________    |               |")
      print ("|               ||ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ|   .|               |")
      print ("|               | -------   |                 |")
      print ("|                |_________|                  |")
      print ("|_____________________________________________|")

        …

class Slime(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.name = "Slime"
        self.level = 1
        self.ATK = 1
        self.DEF = 3
        self.curHP = 5
        self.maxHP = 5
    def print(self):
      print ("--------------------[FIGHT]-------------------")
      print ("|                       ______                |")
      print ("|                ______/      \_              |")
      print ("|              _/               \             |")
      print ("|             /    \     /       \_           |")
      print ("|            /    0       0        \          |")
      print ("|           /                       \         |")
      print ("|           /        ____            |        |")
      print ("|          /                         |        |")
      print ("|          /                          \       |")
      print ("|         /____________________________\      |")
      print ("|                                             |")
      print ("|                                             |")
      print ("|_____________________________________________|")


def randomEnemy():
  monsters = [Goblin, Slime]
  random_enemy = random.choice(monsters)
  return random_enemy() # instantiate the enemy here

# fighting -----------------------
def fightScreen():
  enemy = randomEnemy()
  …
```

This is much more elegant.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even think about the fact it will get randomized twice because of the way I wrote the if statement. Thank you, it worked :)

Comment: Also, I've only just started learning python a few days ago, still don't know my way around that well, but yes I do intend to remake it with classes and everything